# What is the intuition behind quantile in scipy.stats.beta.ppf?

Tags: probability, descriptive-statistics, cumulative-distribution-function, beta-distribution, scipy

I'm trying to use `scipy.stats.beta.ppf(q, a, b)`, where q is referred to as quantile. I understand how beta works and its details, but I'm not able to make sense of q here (It is also called as lower tail probability). I mean, why lower tail probability here in this function ? What benefit does lower tail probability gives us here ? What exactly does q (the lower tail probability) in the above function mean and how to understand the same and its intuition ?

Comment: Too many questions in a single post…

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be a (univariate) random variable, beta-distributed in your case.

A quantile $q$ is defined as the value $x$ such that $P(X\le x)=q$. That is, quantile $0.5$ is the value $x$ such that half of the density is $x$ or lower. For any symmetric beta distribution, quantile $0.5$ happens to be $0.5$. For asymmetric beta distributions, quantile $0.5$ could be much higher or lower, depending on the specifics of t he density.

If you understand percentiles, quantiles are extremely similar, just expressed on $[0,1]$ rather than $[0,100]$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand quantiles, I just want to understand the same in the context of beta distribution here. For example, The intuition behind the lower tail probability in beta.ppf. The intuition when we set q here to 0.05 (say) and how things change if we set q to 0.90. (I probably didn't frame my question right)

Comment: If you set it to $0.05$, it means $5\%$ of the density is in the part of the distribution at or below the returned quantile value. If you set it to $0.90$, it means $90\%$ of the density is in the part of the distribution at or below the returned quantile value.